# onPolygonClick detects different polygon

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, polygon, shapes

I am using Kotlin in my Android project. MapView is in fragment.

When user selects polygon I change its stroke color. Problem is that sometimes onPolygonClick method detects different polygon. You can see it in this GIF: https://gyazo.com/167aed90529031df01c07d7f583f790e

**onPolygonClick method:**

```
override fun onPolygonClick(polygon: Polygon?) {
        polygons.forEach {
            it.strokeColor = Color.BLACK
        }
        polygon?.strokeColor = Color.WHITE
    }
```

At first, I fetch hexagons from server and then I draw it on map. This is method which is called after data are fetched to **add polygons to the map:**

```
private fun drawRegion(regions: Array<Kraj>) {

        //reset map
        googleMap.clear()
        polygons = ArrayList()

        setMapViewBounds(regions)
        for (region in regions) {
            val rnd = Random()
            val color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))
            for (hexagon in region.hexagons) {
                val options = PolygonOptions()
                for (point in hexagon) {
                    options.add(point)
                }
                options.strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
                options.fillColor(color)
                options.strokeWidth(2.5.toFloat())
                options.clickable(true)
                val pol = googleMap.addPolygon(options)
                pol.tag = region.id
                polygons.add(pol)
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I also save all polygons to polygons array so I can access all of them in onPolygonClick method.

**onMapReady method:**

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {

    map?.let {
        googleMap = it
        googleMap.setMapStyle(
            MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                activity?.applicationContext, R.raw.empty_map_style
            )
        )
    }

    map?.setOnMapClickListener(this)
    map?.setOnPolygonClickListener(this)
    addObservers()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out why MapView detects different polygon, but I figured out a workaround.

In case you have same problem as me, just set your polygon options clickable to **false** (otherwise onMapClick is not working if you tap on polygon), setup onMapClickListener and detect which polygon was clicked:

```
override fun onMapClick(coords: LatLng?) {
        val polygon = polygons.first {PolyUtil.containsLocation(coords!!, it.points, true)}
        val id = polygon?.tag.let { it } as Int
        polygons.forEach {
            it.strokeColor = Color.BLACK
            val itId = it?.tag.let { it } as Int
            if (it == polygon) {
                it.strokeColor = Color.BLUE
            }
        }

        viewModel.userClickedOnPolygonWithId(id)
        polygon?.strokeColor = Color.WHITE
    }
```